# multiple login to access data for each department only

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have requests table that have fields (id, name, date, department, answer) and (req_res1.php) that display all records from the table, I tried to create multiple login to access this form for each department only. I mean in a login form there are  username and password and department name and when user choose user, pass and dept., the form display results for only this department. I tried different things but nothing works.

req_res1.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test')or die ( mysqli_error($connect) ); 
$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 
mysqli_query($connect,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase'); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM requests ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

?>
<html>  
 <head>  
          <title>update and delete records</title> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
    <script src="jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>

    <style>
thead, tr {
    color:black;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
}
th {
    background-color: #66CCFF;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;

}
</style>
    </head>  
    <body dir="rtl"> 
    <br />
<div id="header" align="center">
    <img id="image1" src="img/egate4.png">
    <br /> 
    </div>  
 <div class="container" style="width:1200px;"> 
   <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
    <h3 align="center">requests display</h3><br />      
    <table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>request no</th>
       <th>name</th>
        <th>date of request</th>
    <th>department</th>
    <th>status</th>

      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      echo '
      <tr>
       <td>'.$row["no"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["reqdate"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["dept"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["answer"].'</td>
      </tr>
      ';
     }
     ?>

     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>  
  </div> 
</div> 
 </body>  
</html>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#editable_table').Tabledit({
      url:'req_res2.php',
      columns:{
       identifier:[0, "no"],
       editable:[[1, 'name'], [2, 'reqdate'], [3, 'dept'],[4, 'answer']]
      },
      restoreButton:false,
      onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
       if(data.req_res2 == 'delete')
       {
        $('#'+data.id).remove();
       }
      }
     });

});  
 </script>
```

req_res2.php

```
<?php  
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test')or die ( mysqli_error($connect) ); 

$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($connect,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase'); 

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["name"]);
$no = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["no"]);
$reqdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["reqdate"]);
$answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["answer"]);

if($input["action"] === 'edit')
{
 $query = "
 UPDATE requests 
 SET name = '".$name."', 
 answer = '".$answer."' 
 WHERE id = '".$input["id"]."'
 ";

 mysqli_query($connect, $query);

}
if($input["action"] === 'delete')
{
 $query = "
 DELETE FROM requests 
 WHERE id = '".$input["id"]."'
 ";
 mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}

echo json_encode($input);

?>
```

Comment: A possible suggestion?  Do you already have a way to know which department that a logged-in user belongs to?  If so, this could be a way to avoid the hassle(s) that you're facing now, by using that information "behind the scenes" to limit the department info to the logged-in user.

Comment: Paul T, thank you for your answer, actually i plan to create one user for each department , that responsible for edit or delete his department data. so its known to me which user belongs to which department.

Comment: Since you said that you know the user's department, I figured that was the route you were going to take (to get the user's associated department after login), so that they don't have to enter the department at login? This would be the best way to go and save the hassle that you mentioned in your question.  Am I possibly missing something that has not been clarified?

Comment: thank you Paul T. , its clear for me but i still miss how i filter the form data after login !!!!! i mean for example if i login for user 2 for dept 2  with his password, how the data on the req_res1.php and req_res2.php will show  dept 2 data only!!

Comment: Ideally, the information could be stored with a session, as is sometimes done with user-related info (to pass between web page after login), such as their name, but you do not appear to be using sessions in either file. In addition, I do **not** see that `dept` is used anywhere in the `req_res2.php` file, but only in the first file?  Some way, the dept. needs to be used at your `requests` query, but it appears that you select all records before any filtering can be applied to this query.